# Using NPM modules

Tags: node.js, json, npm, require, package.json

I'm currently learning about NPM modules and have a very basic question. Let's say I have my `package.json` file which looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "express.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
  }
}
```

In my `express.js` file I can then `require` and use lodash like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

_.each(numbers, function (number, i){
    console.log(number)
});
```

I now have two questions:

1. How can I display this code in a basic HTML document instead of just the console?
2. How can I require/use node modules in another js file? E.g. if I want to require `lodash` from another js file?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. There a several ways of doing this, perhaps the simplest is to use a template engine such as [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) to return html data to a client.

For example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ejs = require("ejs");

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    const fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana'];
    const html = ejs.render(`<ul>
    <% for (let fruit of fruits) { %>
        <li> <%= fruit %> </li>
    <% } %>
    </ul>`, { fruits });
    res.status(200).send(html);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Just run the script, then goto http://localhost:3000 to see the result.

2. You should be able to use the same syntax to include modules in your other files, e.g. foo.js, just include:

   const _ = require("lodash");

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Regarding the second answer. If I include the same way from antoher js file then what is set to the "main" in my package.json, it gives me the following msg in the console of the browser: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Require is not supported on the client side (unless you use browserify) I would suggest using a script link when running client side code, e.g.  include <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script> in the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

you can display syntax using `<pre>` tag

```html
<pre>
const _ = require('lodash');
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

_.each(numbers, function (number, i){
    console.log(number)
});
</pre>
```